# ResourceWarning about unclosed socket from PySpark toPandas() in unit tests

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, python-unittest

I'm getting a ResourceWarning in every unit test I run on Spark like this:

```
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/socket.py:775: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=6, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 37512), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 38975)>
  self._sock = None
    ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I tracked it down to [`DataFrame.toPandas()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas.html). Example:

```
import unittest    
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

class PySparkTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_convert_to_pandas_df(self):
        spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]").getOrCreate()
        rawData = spark.range(10)
        print("XXX 1")
        pdfData = rawData.toPandas()
        print("XXX 2")
        print(pdfData)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

You'll see the 2 ResourceWarnings just before the `XXX 2` output line.

However, if you run the same code outside unittest, you *won't* get the resource warning!

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]").getOrCreate()    
rawData = spark.range(10)    
print("XXX 1")
pdfData = rawData.toPandas()
print("XXX 2")
print(pdfData)
```

So, is unittest doing something to cause this resource warning in `toPandas()`? I appreciate I could  hide the resource warning (e.g., see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26620811/1843329) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65275151/1843329)), but I'd rather not get the resource warning in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a environment variable called `PYTHONWARNINGS` to the value `ignore` before you run your tests or use the `-W ignore` switch the python interpreter has.

Comment: Thanks; I know I could suppress the warning but I want to know what's causing it in the first place. I might ignore it until a fix is found. Is there a bug in `toPandas()` or unittest for example?

Comment: E.g., I can suppress both ResourceWarnings just by adding this to the `setUp()` method of my unit tests: `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=ResourceWarning, message="unclosed <socket.socket")`

Comment: Using your example code (not the unittest) and running it through `python -W once` gives me the same resource warning. So my guess it, that this is a problem with pyspark, not with unittest

Comment: Update to my previous comment: moving the warnings filter to `setUpClass()` also works, and should be more efficient than running it before every single unit test via `setUp()`.